# Constructing a tuple from values returned by member functions of objects inside another tuple

Tags: c++, c++17, return-value, variadic-templates, stdtuple

(This could be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info), so I'm providing some background information prior to the actual question.)

## Background

I currently have a function (not a template) that computes different hash types (CRC32, MD5, SHA1, etc.) The data comes from a provider that can only provide a pointer to a chunk of the data at a time. The function computes the hashes on chunks of data iteratively.

Advancing to the next chunk is a very costly operation (involves decompression) and it can only go forward. Also the architecture must be kept zero-copy. As a result, all the selected hashes must be computed at once while iterating on the same chunks of data. Hash type selection is done through `bool` parameters:

```
std::tuple<uint32_t, QByteArray, QByteArray, QByteArray>
computeHashes(DataProvider& data, bool do_crc, bool do_md5, bool do_sha1,
              bool do_sha256);
```

If one of the flags is `false`, the caller ignores the corresponding empty tuple element.

## Actual Question

I am very unhappy with the above API. So I decided to write a cleaner looking function template. No boolean switches and no dummy tuple elements in the return value:

```
auto [crc, sha256] = computeHashes<Hash::CRC32, Hash::MD5>(data_provider);
```

I got the code mostly working, except for the last step where I need to actually return the results. This is trimmed down from the real code, and with only two hash functions in order to keep the example as short as possible:

```
enum class Hash { CRC32, MD5 };

template <HashType> struct Hasher
{};

template<> struct Hasher<HashType::CRC32>
{
    void addData(const char* data, int len);
    uint32_t result() const;
};

template<> struct Hasher<HashType::MD5>
{
    void addData(const char* data, int len);
    QByteArray result() const;
};

template <HashType... hash_types>
auto computeHashes(DataProvider& provider)
{
    std::tuple<Hasher<hash_types>...> hashers;

    while (provider.hasMoreChunks()) {
        auto [chunk, len] = provider.nextChunk();
        std::apply([chunk, len](auto&... hasher)
                       { (..., hasher.addData(chunk, len); },
                   hashers);
    }
    return std::make_tuple( ??? );
}
```

I'm stuck at the last step: how do I return each result? A hard-coded return would look this:

```
return std::make_tuple(res, std::get<0>(hashers).result(),
                       std::get<1>(hashers).result());
```

This isn't suitable of course. How do I do this?

Comment: You might consider looking into Hana, which has a whole bunch of functional utilities for tuples.

Comment: something like `return std::apply([](auto&&... hasher){ return std::tuple(hasher.result()...); }, hashers);` ?

Comment: @Sopel That does work! Make that into an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

since `std::apply` forwards returned values by `decltype(auto)` you can just construct a tuple with `std::apply` and return it.
This can be coalesced with your transformations into one call.

```
template <HashType... hash_types>
static auto computeHashes(DataProvider& provider)
{
    return std::apply(
        [&provider](auto&&... hashers) { 
            while (provider.hasMoreChunks()) 
            {
                auto [chunk, len] = provider.nextChunk();
                (..., hashers.addData(chunk, len));
            }

            return std::make_tuple(std::move(hashers.result())...);
        },
        std::tuple<Hasher<hash_types>...>{}
    );
}
```